# Font size change with theme() not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting barplots. I have written a script, however when I want to change the front size of the texts in the barplots, it does not work. For example, whether I write `axis.text.y= element_text(size=6)` or `axis.text.y= element_text(size=15)`, I have the same text size. I don't know where the problem is in my script.

```
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=treatment, y=value, fill=R2)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge")
p <- p + labs(list(title = "title", x = "xaxis", y = "yaxis"))
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values=c(grey(0.4), grey(0.8)))
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=6), axis.text.y= element_text(size=6), axis.title = element_text(size=6), title = element_text(size=4))
p <- p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=100), lty=2)
p <- p + ylim(0,100)
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(limits=c('T','F','S', 'R'))#to reorder x axis
p <- p + theme_bw()
p <- p + theme(legend.position="none")
p
```

Comment: You should put all the `theme` together, for clarity. And please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: put the `theme_bw` before changing defaults

Comment: @rawr Thanks a lot! it is now working when I put the `theme_bw` before changing defaults!