# Modify pre-defined ggplot2 theme

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the following code to turn my x-axis legend by 90 degree:

```
theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0)
)
```

Now I would like to use an existing theme, specifically `theme_light()` and keep my x-axis turned. Is there a way to modify just the `axis.text.x` property of `theme_light()` without needing to redefine the entire theme?

**Solution**

```
ggplot(...) +
theme_light() +
theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0)
)
```

Comment: `ggplot() + theme_light() + theme(your_changes_here)`, in that order.

Comment: If you actually want to change the theme itself, see `?theme_update`.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033621/font-size-change-with-theme-not-working)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7459796/680068

Comment: @behas Rather than editing your question with the solution, you should put it as an answer.