# Center titles and subtitles nd in theme_minimal()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following plot:

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed)) + 
  geom_bar()+
  labs(title="speed",
       subtitle="other info")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

the theme layer centers the plot title and subtitle.

However, when I add `theme_minimal()` the centering does not apply anymore.
I guess theme_minimal overwrites the theme specifications.

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed)) + 
  geom_bar()+
  labs(title="speed",
       subtitle="other info")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
 theme_minimal()
```

Trying to specifiy the title and subtitle position in theme minimal does not the way I though it might:

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed)) + 
  geom_bar()+
  labs(title="speed",
       subtitle="other info")+
  theme_minimal(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Any suggestions how to center title and subtitle from within `theme_minimal()`?

Comment: You need to change the order, first `theme_minimal` and then `theme` with your specificiations

Comment: @kath Thank you very much...that was embarrassingly simple :-D

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030903/modify-pre-defined-ggplot2-theme, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033621/font-size-change-with-theme-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is correct and adding `theme_minimal` after you specify a `theme` overrides the settings. Thus, you need to change the order of your `ggplot`-call.

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  labs(title = "speed", subtitle = "other info") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

This comes from the layering in ggplot, you can also see this, when you specify e.g. a color scale twice, then you get a warning, saying that the first one will be overwritten. Also your plot show does values on top which are plotted last when you plot several layers (i.e. several `geom_point`-calls).

Comment: Great! Yes, the layering I was aware of. That works nicely now